# Does Austrian logical positivism have anything to see with Comte's positivism?

Tags: logical-positivism, positivism

Does Austrian logical positivism have anything to see with Comte's positivism?

I never saw any direct relation between the two, but the two have the same term in their name, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Only indirectly... Logical positivism > [Vienna Circle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vienna-circle/) > *Erst Mach Verein* > [Ernst Mach](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ernst-mach/) => 18th Cent positivism: Comte, Mill. The key differences are: Comte more interested in ethics and sociology vs Mach interested in geometry and physics. Comte's *Course on Positive Philosophy* and *System of Positive Polity, or Treatise on Sociology, Instituting the Religion of Humanity* are intended as a "system" and the rejection of phil systems (e.g. Hegel) were one of the cornerstone of Log.Positivism.

Comment: Some details can be found into Christian Damböck, [*Rudolf Carnap and Wilhelm Dilthey: “German” Empiricism in the Aufbau*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-007-3929-1_5).

Comment: Curious about your reasons for asking this. Are you maybe trying to understand the intellectual background that gave birth to Jungianism?